# Minimum Deletions Python, While Loop Conditional statement behavior

Tags: python, algorithm, while-loop

I've been trying to solve LeetCode problem 1647. 
The goal is to provide the minimum number of times we need to make a deletion in the string to make the frequency of each letter in that string unique.
I tried to solve it myself but had quite a hard time and found a very close solution to what I had in mind. 
Unfortunately I'm having a hard time understanding it due to what I believe might be some Python specific behavior.

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'aaabbcc'
letterFrequency = Counter(s)

frequencyValues = letterFrequency.values()

frequencySet = set()

count = 0

for frequencyValue in frequencyValues:
    while frequencyValue and frequencyValue in frequencySet:
        count += 1
        frequencyValue -= 1
    frequencySet.add(frequencyValue)

print(count)
```

The part I specifically don't understand is *the conditional statement on the while loop*. 
I know that this specific conditional `frequencyValue and frequencyValue in frequencySet` is checking to see if the values are in the `frequencySet` though I am not sure how this conditional is also making us check if the `frequencyValue` is redundant and thus adding an extra deletion.

I've included the link to the actual LeetCode question [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-deletions-to-make-character-frequencies-unique/).

Any advice would be much appreciated as I'm trying to prep for an interview ^^

Comment: It is equivalent to `while frequencyValue > 0 and frequencyValue in frequencySet:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### explanation

Counter is a dictionary with letter: counts values

for each letter in values, if the count was already encountered (i.e. collected in the frequencySet) you must start to count how many changes are needed to have only unique values.
From this the algorithm is:

at each duplicate value:
count inc by1
value dec by 1

at the end of the loop you have a set of uniq values and count is the total moves to reach the goal.

ps: good luck for the interview

Comment: *"starting from the bigger to the smallest"*: where in the program this is ensured?

Comment: U are right @trincot encountering order is maintained as described here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter
fixed description